# IBatis and SQL Server on Java

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc, ibatis

I'm trying to make a Java connection with SQL Server, but I'm facing some problemas. I believe I not specifying correctly the database name. My SQL Map is something like

```
    <transactionManager type="JDBC">
    <dataSource type="SIMPLE">
        <property value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" name="JDBC.Driver" />
        <property value="jdbc:sqlserver://${host}:${port}" name="JDBC.ConnectionURL" />
        <property value="${name}" name="JDBC.DatabaseName" />
        <property value="${username}" name="JDBC.Username" />
        <property value="${password}" name="JDBC.Password" />
    </dataSource>
</transactionManager>
```

I connection is successfully, but when I try to retrieve some value from one of ours tables, it's show the error:  Invalid object name '[table name]'

How can I specify my database name in this SQL Map?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always know that **JDBC.DatabaseName** doesn't exists, but I tried. Now, I try changing this key and I found, in SQLMap docs, Driver.Key is used to set driver properties, so I change **JDBC.DatabaseName** to **Driver.DatabaseName**, and It works!!!!!

```
<transactionManager type="JDBC">
    <dataSource type="SIMPLE">
        <property value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" name="JDBC.Driver" />
        <property value="jdbc:sqlserver://${host}:${port}" name="JDBC.ConnectionURL" />
        <property value="${name}" name="Driver.DatabaseName" />
        <property value="${username}" name="JDBC.Username" />
        <property value="${password}" name="JDBC.Password" />
    </dataSource>
</transactionManager>
```